# Sending string using python in a raspberry pi 3b+ mesh connection via bluetooth

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, bluetooth, bluez

I am currently working with three raspi 3b+ that should have a mesh connection via Bluetooth. The devices sense a sound and will try to send it to the other devices. Now, my questions are:

1. How will I connect these 3 devices via Bluetooth mesh connection?
2. Can I write a code using python for the sending of sound to the other devices?
3. Is there a python library/module that I can use to send the sound to other devices?

Comment: 1. How you will do it is on you. 2. That depends on your python skills. 3. Not python, but quality content: https://www.bluetooth.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Developer-Study-Guide-How-to-Deploy-BlueZ-on-a-Raspberry-Pi-Board-as-a-Bluetooth-Mesh-Provisioner.pdf https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54827686/bluetooth-mesh-for-raspberry-pi

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.